# React native calendars change selectedDay

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-calendars

I'm developing my react native application. I'm using react native calendars. I want to change selectedDay of agenda when new props arrived to the screen.

My code:

```
 componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
      if (this.props !== nextProps) {
        //this.setState(nextProps);

        this.setState({
          newFinished: nextProps.finished,
          newId: nextProps.id,

        });

        //console.log('Next props ' + JSON.stringify(nextProps));

        if(nextProps.navigation.state.params.range !== undefined) {
          //console.log('Pridem noter');
          this.setState({
            minDate: nextProps.navigation.state.params.range[0],
            maxDate: nextProps.navigation.state.params.range[1],
            selectedDay:  nextProps.navigation.state.params.range[0]
          });

          setTimeout(() => {
            this.onDayPress(nextProps.navigation.state.params.range[0]);
          },200);
        }
      }
    }
```

I don't know why selected day didn't change at all. Even though I receive props...

Does any one have similar problem?

Comment: What's your RN version? Because componentWillReceiveProps is deprecated.

Comment: "react-native": "^0.55.4",